# Setting to XMLHttpRequest asynchronous doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to learn Ajax now i don't know how to set XMLHttpRequest Asynchronous. i've tryed some other post about ajax but can't make sense of it. Sorry if this already asked.

In the following code i try to console.log the XMLHttpRequest object.
i've linked it to a local text file in the same folder.

the problem is that when is set request.open parameter to true it does't work. Its only works when its set to false but i read that this is not asynchronous.

I am using XAMPP for a server. Also i've tryed it on a differnt server form school.

If there are anny questions please ask me.
thanks

```
var request;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    request = new ActiveXObject("Mircosoft.XMLHTTP");
}
//this open function 
request.open('GET', 'text.txt', true);
request.send();
if(request.status===200){
console.log(request);
document.writeln(request.responseText);
}
```

Comment: That is set up to be synchronous.... asynchronous uses [onreadstatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) or onload. Read MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of it being asynchronous is that it won't lock up the JavaScript engine until the response has arrived. So with your current code, you are trying to read the response before it exists.

You need to use an event handler to process the data after it has arrived.

```
function processData() {
    document.writeln(this.responseText);
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'text.txt');
request.addEventListener("load", processData);
request.send();
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You've to wait the response with request.onreadystatechange function

```
var request;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


request.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
      document.writeln(request.responseText);
    }
}

//this open function 
request.open('GET', 'text.txt', true);
request.send();
```